# Cannot uninstall wrapt 1.10.11

Tags: update, packages, pip

I am trying to install Tensorflow 2.3 on the raspberry pi 4 2GB using this guide (https://itnext.io/installing-tensorflow-2-3-0-for-raspberry-pi3-4-debian-buster-11447cb31fc4) but I keep getting the error: ERROR: Cannot uninstall wrapt. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

I have tried using pip install wrapt --upgrade --ignore-installed. It then installs wrapt 1.12 but when I try to install Tensorflow the wrapt 1.10 version gets picked up and I get the same error.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS. I want to use tflite to run my models, but need tensorflow as I am using keras for preprocessing the images which requires tensorflow 2.2 at least. If anyone can guide me in a direction to perform the below processing without keras I would not need to install Tensorflow and I can avoid this error.

````
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
    processed_image = tf.keras.applications.efficientnet.preprocess_input(test_image)```
````

Comment: Requirements state Python 3 but you used `pip` in your question which is for Python 2... maybe using pip3 will solve some of the issues (or it was a typing error)?

Answer (score 0):

Remove file wrapt-1.10.11.egg-info
by command
`sudo rm /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/wrapt-1.10.11.egg-info`

Then install tensorflow again
`sudo -H pip3 install tensorflow-2.3.0-cp37-none-linux_armv7l.whl`